# Wired network for a lot of ESP8266 / ESP8285

Tags: i2c, spi, esp8266, wifi

I found [this project at GitHub](https://github.com/Neumi/wifi_camera), and I would like to do the same but add a few improvements.

1. Rotate modules, according to this radiation pattern: [image] [image]
   Would it work better?
2. As I understand ESP8266 doesn’t have I2C slave role so it needs to be implemented on software level. Probably a better way would be to use daisy-chaining SPI, or if someone has a better idea what network / interface should be used?

Comment: Sergey Tytarenko - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that if a post copies or adapts content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material, the *original* source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.).

Comment: (continued) The images in your question do not appear at the link currently given. Therefore please [edit] your question to add the original image source name & link for each image, unless it is completely your own work (and please remember it's your responsibility to add any required references in future). Thanks. (Also, as you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as the site rules here differ from typical forums.)